# Getting an object not found error when using the predict function in R

Tags: r, object, predict

I have this code and it works:

```
# Load the data
Prostate <- read.csv("prostate.csv")

# Create the fitted models
Prostate.Fit.Cubic    <- lm(formula = lpsa ~ poly(x = Prostate$pgg45, degree = 3), data = Prostate)
Prostate.Fit.Spline.1 <- lm(formula = lpsa ~ ns(x = Prostate$pgg45, knots = c(15, 45)),     data = Prostate)
Prostate.Fit.Spline.2 <- lm(formula = lpsa ~ ns(x = Prostate$pgg45, knots = c(25, 50, 75)), data = Prostate)

# Use the models to predict lpsa
X <- data.frame(seq(from = 0, to = 96, by = 1))
colnames(X) <- "X"

Prostate.PGG45                    <- Prostate$pgg45
Prostate.LPSA                     <- Prostate$lpsa
Prostate.Fit.Cubic.Predictions    <- predict(object = Prostate.Fit.Cubic,    newdata = X, type = "response")
Prostate.Fit.Spline.1.Predictions <- predict(object = Prostate.Fit.Spline.1, newdata = X, type = "response")
Prostate.Fit.Spline.2.Predictions <- predict(object = Prostate.Fit.Spline.2, newdata = X, type = "response")

Prostate.All <- data.frame(cbind(Prostate.PGG45,
                                 Prostate.LPSA,
                                 Prostate.Fit.Cubic.Predictions,
                                 Prostate.Fit.Spline.1.Predictions,
                                 Prostate.Fit.Spline.2.Predictions))

# Plot lpsa vs pgg45 with the predictions
ggplot(data = Prostate.All, mapping = aes(x = Prostate.PGG45, y = Prostate.LPSA)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Prostate.LPSA), size = 2, color = "grey") +
  geom_point(aes(y = Prostate.Fit.Cubic.Predictions), size = 2, color = "orange") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Prostate.Fit.Cubic.Predictions), color = "orange") +
  geom_point(aes(y = Prostate.Fit.Spline.1.Predictions), size = 2, color = "purple") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Prostate.Fit.Spline.1.Predictions), color = "purple") +
  geom_point(aes(y = Prostate.Fit.Spline.2.Predictions), size = 2, color = "green") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Prostate.Fit.Spline.2.Predictions), color = "green") +
  labs(title = "Log Prostate Specific Anitgen (LPSA) vs. Percentage of Gleason Scores of 4 or 5 (PGG45)", x = "PGG45", y = "LPSA") +
  theme_bw()
```

I have very similar code and it doesn't work:

```
# Load the data
Heart.Train <- read.csv("heart_training.csv")
Heart.Test  <- read.csv("heart_test.csv")
Heart       <- data.frame(rbind(Heart.Train, Heart.Test))

# Create the fitted models
Heart.Fit             <- glm(formula = target ~ thalach,
                             data = Heart,
                             family = binomial)
Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.2 <- glm(formula = target ~ ns(x = Heart$thalach, df = 2),
                             data = Heart,
                             family = binomial)
Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.5 <- glm(formula = target ~ ns(x = Heart$thalach, df = 5),
                             data = Heart,
                             family = binomial)

# Use the models to predict target
X <- data.frame(seq(from = min(Heart$thalach), to = max(Heart$thalach), length.out = 303))
colnames(X) <- "X"

Heart.Thalach                     <- Heart$thalach
Heart.Target                      <- Heart$target
Heart.Fit.Predictions             <- predict(object = Heart.Fit,
                                             newdata = X,
                                             type = "response")
Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.2.Predictions <- predict(object = Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.2,
                                             newdata = X,
                                             type = "response")
Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.5.Predictions <- predict(object = Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.5,
                                             newdata = X,
                                             type = "response")

# Combine data, predictions, and group names
Heart.Target.Group          <- cbind(Heart.Target,
                                     rep(x = "Raw", times = length(Heart.Target)))
Heart.Fit.Group             <- cbind(Heart.Fit.Predictions,
                                     rep(x = "Log", times = length(Heart.Fit.Predictions)))
Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.2.Group <- cbind(Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.2.Predictions,
                                     rep(x = "DF2", times = length(Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.2.Predictions)))
Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.5.Group <- cbind(Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.5.Predictions,
                                     rep(x = "DF5", times = length(Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.5.Predictions)))

Heart.All <- data.frame(rbind(Heart.Thalach.Group,
                              Heart.Target.Group,
                              Heart.Fit.Group,
                              Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.2.Group,
                              Heart.Fit.Spline.DF.5.Group))
```

The error I'm getting is for this line near the top of the second chunk of code:

```
Heart.Fit.Predictions             <- predict(object = Heart.Fit,
                                             newdata = X,
                                             type = "response")
```

The error is as follow:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'thalach' not found

I've looked for a solution and tried everything I can think of. Any thoughts? I'm trying to get Heart.Fit to take the values from X and predict the response. It worked in the previous chunk. I'm guessing there's something a little different with the model I created, but I'm confused.

Comment: The names in `newdata` need to match the columns you used when fitting the model. You seem to just be setting the column name to "X" but you didn not use `X` in your formula. Also, make sure not to use `$` in formulas. That will prevent your from being able to predict on new data. All values will come from `data=` parameter so no need for `$`

Comment: Does that mean my first code chunk is wrong? In that chunk, I created a variable X and used that as my `newdata` and didn't get any errors. I tried to do the same for the second chunk and got an error.

Comment: Yes. It looks wrong. I don't know whether `X` is meant to be `lpsa` or `pgg45`. Perhaps you have a global `lspa` variable.